# Assume role with WebIdentity request in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, service-accounts, sts

The microservice in Kubernetes needs to access the API's hosted in a private AWS API gateway. The authentication and authorization is AWS_IAM.

The Kubernetes has the proper environment variables
AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE
AWS_ROLE_ARN

The pods in Kubernetes are running with service account. For AWS_IAM, we need the session token to be generated.

1. WebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider.create() helps to generate only access key and access secret. This does not generate the session token.
2. So basically, we need to convert the sts cli command to Java

   ```sh
   aws sts assume-role-with-web-identity \
    --role-arn $AWS_ROLE_ARN \
    --role-session-name mysession \
    --web-identity-token file://$AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE \
    --duration-seconds 1000 > /tmp/irp-cred.txt
   ```
3. I am passing the correct things in the Java code

   ```java
   AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityRequest assumeRoleWithWebIdentityRequest = AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityRequest.builder()
                   .webIdentityToken("file:///var/run/secrets/eks.amazonaws.com/serviceaccount/token")
                           .roleArn("arn:aws:iam::*:role/eks/test")
                                   .roleSessionName("user")
                                           .build();
   log.info("AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityRequest:{}",assumeRoleWithWebIdentityRequest.toString());

   StsClient stsClient =  StsClient.builder()
             .region(region).build();
   AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityResponse assumeRoleWithWebIdentityResponse = stsClient.assumeRoleWithWebIdentity(assumeRoleWithWebIdentityRequest);
   log.info("AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityResponse:{}",assumeRoleWithWebIdentityResponse.toString());

   Credentials credentials = assumeRoleWithWebIdentityResponse.credentials();
   log.info("credentials, AccessKey:{},AccessSecret:{},AccessToken:{}",credentials.accessKeyId(),credentials.secretAccessKey(),credentials.sessionToken();
   ```
4. I am using below dependency

   ```xml
   <dependency>
       <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
       <artifactId>acm</artifactId>
       <version>2.17.102</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

But this is not working.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Finally Found the solution. Instead of
'''
 .webIdentityToken("file:///var/run/secrets/eks.amazonaws.com/serviceaccount/token")
                        .roleArn("arn:aws:iam::*:role/eks/test")
'''
Read the file and then get the token. Use FILE READ classes and then use that token in the webIdentityToken.

Thank you

Comment: getting following error with same code: 
Unable to load credentials from SystemPropertyCredentialsProvider():

Can you please help where I am wrong?

Comment: Nagesh Dalave I am experiencing the same, have you progressed on this at all? I have my token read and as Gaurav Bhandari shows it also works with CLI for me but when it comes to the AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityRequest  
"..... InvocationTargetException: Unable to load credentials from any of the providers in the chain AwsCredentialsProviderChain...."